# Poetry script, command not found

Tags: python, python-poetry

I created a project using poetry. My project structure is like this -

```
/
pyproject.toml
winshift/
  __init__.py
  cli.py
... more sturf
```

My file `cli.py` includes a function `main` and in my *pyproject.toml* I defined -

```
...
[tools.poetry.scripts]
winshift-cli = "winshift.cli:main"
```

But when I try to run `poetry run` winshift-cli` I get -

```
Command not found: winshift-cli
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work. I am able to run my *cli* in different ways and work properly.

- `poetry run python -m winshift.cli`
- `poetry run python winshift/cli.py`
- `python -m winshift.cli`

I know that scripts are added to `$(poetry env info -p)/bin`folder, but in this case that is not happening. I have no clue what is wrong.

Here is the full code for reference: https://github.com/rkmax/winshift-python

Comment: Have you run `poetry install` since adding `winshift-cli` to the scripts?

Comment: yes, of course. I did run poetry install, tried to recreate the poetry environment multiple times and get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, the section name is incorrect `[tools.poetry.scripts]` the correct one ios `[tool.poetry.scripts]`